# Changing the display properties of a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used table cell to this on my site:

[image]

But as you can see on the picture:

[image]

The mobile view looks a bit odd so I would like the green no now be displayed horizontally and it's cells underneath each other.

I have checked few answers from SO already but could understand properly.
Here my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/y7wqj55p/2/

Tried changing the display properties to inherit but nothing much happens:

[image]

```
tr{
  display: inherit;
}
```

How can I make green bars be displayed horizontally on top of their cells?
Hope I could make some sense. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are massively abusing tables for layout purposes here - like using empty table cells to create the green bars ... You should scrap that, then create a proper _list_ of team members - and then format that to look as you want on desktop and mobile. The green bars should be borders, and then it will be trivial to make them from a border-left to a border-top via CSS.

Comment: The green bar has a paragraph with rotation if you check on my jsfiddle...and you can see the same paragraph floating outside the green bar from the last picture.
I initially did not know how to do the chart and was advised her e on SO to use tables.
Can you please and a live example of your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this to your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 550px){
    .five-sixths, .four-fifths, .four-sixths, .one-fifth, .one-fourth, .one-half, .one-sixth, .one-third, .three-fifths, .three-fourths, .three-sixths, .two-fifths, .two-fourths, .two-sixths, .two-thirds {

        width: 100% !important;
    }
    td, tr {
        display: block;
    }
    p.rotate.column-second {
        position: initial;
        -webkit-transform: inherit;
         transform: inherit;
        -o-transform: inherit;
        -moz-transform: inherit;
    }
    td.column {
        width: inherit;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    table img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .org-chart td {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't use tables like this. But if you really have to, you could do:

```
@media(mind-width:992px){
    tr, td {
        display: block;
    }
}
```